# Cordrova background geolocation phonegap build fails

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap-build

I have installed cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation

But the build fails on android with this message and I cant figure out whats wrong.

Here is the error message from the phonegap build log.

---

- Where:
  Build file '/project/build.gradle' line: 253
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'project'.

  > Could not get unknown property 'GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

---

This is my config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="no.twn.androidapp" version="1.0.6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>temp</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.5.0" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="15" />
    <preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <engine name="ios" spec="^4.4.0" />
    <engine name="android" spec="^6.3.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation" spec="^2.3.3">
        <variable name="GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" value="+" />
        <variable name="ICON" value="@mipmap/icon" />
        <variable name="SMALL_ICON" value="@mipmap/icon" />
        <variable name="ACCOUNT_NAME" value="@string/app_name" />
        <variable name="ACCOUNT_LABEL" value="@string/app_name" />
        <variable name="ACCOUNT_TYPE" value="$PACKAGE_NAME.account" />
        <variable name="CONTENT_AUTHORITY" value="$PACKAGE_NAME" />
        <variable name="ALWAYS_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="This app always requires location tracking" />
    </plugin>
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been struggling to run this plugin in Phonegap Build these days as well and here are my findings:

Unfortunately the 2.3.x versions seems to work only on v2.6.0 android which is not [**supported**](https://build.phonegap.com/current-support) yet.
Try using v2.2.5 of the plugin, is seems to be working in PB (since version 3 of this plugin is not yet released in cordova repo).

Answer (score 0):

This may help:
For compatibility with other plugins you may also set specific google play version. Following example will lock google play services to version 11.0.1 for compatibility with phonegap-plugin-push. Note: Always consult documentation of other plugins to figure out correct GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
I tried update android sdk,but didn't work.

[[image]

I tried remove and add platform android,but didn't work.
I tried remove and add cordova-plugin-backgroud-geolocation,and it worked.

[[image]

Comment: I see by your image that the build i successful, but it is working when you build it though phonegap. I also have a successful build on my machine but not when i build it with phonegap. Btw. It seems to me that phonegap uses a lower version of android than i use 6.1.3 i use 6.3.0 and i think 6.3.0 is required by the plugin.